# Disclaimer Popup on Chatter Group

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, javascript, chatter

I want to add a disclaimer message on a chatter group. When new user join chatter group he/she needs to accept disclaimer message. Can anybody help me on this because there is no standard way to do this. Is their any way to create visualforce page and show as popup on specific chatter group. Please provide example if anyone have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this myself before, but have some directions for you to look into.

1. you can look into creating some Apex triggers that does customized things upon a member joined a group. This is most likely going to get you what you want.
2. put the disclaimer out as an announcement on the group, that way it'll always show up on the side of the group page. this does not prohibit the user from using the group though.
3. make a feed post about the disclaimer, use the pin post feature and pin it on top of the post so it always shows up as the first item of the group feed. this does not prohibit the user from using the group though.
4. make the group private so nobody can join, and create a manual workflow around that - only people who accepted the disclaimer separately can then be added to the group by the group admin(s). the public can still discover this private group and request for membership. this is the most labor heavy but will for sure achieve what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using simple Lightning Flows. This [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation) could give you a complete understanding of how a flow works and how you can configure it.

Also a simple google search got me something more similar to your requirement. Make this a reference and build your own flow: [Login Flows with Salesforce Community for Terms and Conditions](https://medium.com/@nialljpmurphy/how-to-use-login-flows-with-salesforce-community-for-terms-and-conditions-acceptance-77228405c01b)